# getting the variance using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I want to get the variance of each column in a csv file for that  I've wrote the following :

```
import numpy as np
import csv
import collections
Training        = 'Training.csv'
inputFile       = open(Training,'r',newline='')
cols_values     = collections.defaultdict(list)
numericalValues = []
reader = csv.reader(inputFile)
row = next(reader)

for row in reader:
    for col, value in enumerate(row):
        cols_values[col].append(value)
        numericalValues.append(cols_values[col])

np.var(numericalValues[0], dtype=np.float64)
```

I get an error in `np.var` line :

```
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

any idea what I'm missing, the values are definitely digits !

Comment: are all of these double precision?

Comment: no but even without type definition  I get the same error

Comment: Of course, because what is telling you is that you have different data types. So no matter what you specify (or not) you need to have same data type for all of values. Hence, convert the array to a single data type before using computing the variance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason to not use Pandas for this?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
Training = 'Training.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(Training)
df.apply(np.var, axis=0)      # can also use `df.var(...)`
```

You want to make sure that all of your columns have numerical values. You can also use `np.nanvar` to ignore `NaN` values if you choose.

Comment: thanks for replying it did work now I got need to understand why !